# Uninstalling add-ons Subscriptions causing DB error

Tags: custom-fields, module, addons, devdemon-subscriptions

I'm trying to uninstall two add-ons that we have no intention of using on the production version of this project (Store and Subscriptions). Unfortunately, every time I go to uninstall I get this message when I try to view the fields in a channel field group:

[image]

If I'm reading that right, it's telling me that the table for the add-on I just uninstalled doesn't exist. Um, duh?

Since the error **seems** to only occur when I try to view custom fields, I assumed it was because one of my fields was still set to the field type for this add-on (Subscriptions). I've double- and triple-checked (including looking at the database directly, in the `exp_channel_fields` table) and not a single custom field is set to use the Subscriptions field type. I also checked Matrix since we're using it quite a bit and none of the columns are set to use that field type.

Truly stuck. :/

---

EDIT: This is NOT limited to just the Subscriptions add-on. It also happens when trying to uninstall Expresso Store.

Comment: Have you checked the exp_subs_preferences table? Does it exist? Are you on a MSM build using site_id 1. Have you ever used the Subscription add-on? Although strange, you may have to go into the settings for the add-on, save settings so it stores elements in the table, then it might be happy. What errors do you get with th Store add-on? If neither add-on has any tables in your database (exp_store...), then it sounds like the uninstaller bugged at the last stage, but please supply some more information and I can give instructions for cleaning out the add-ons completely.

Comment: Sorry, meant to add, you don't actually state, but could you confirm did both add-ons successfully uninstall and therefore are no longer in EE? And when you uninstalled, did you uninstall everything - Extension and fieldtype? The error you're getting is (I expect) because of a hook or the fieldtype is still installed.

Comment: Nope, the table doesn't exist because I uninstalled the add-on. Not an MSM site (that was never turned on) I get the same type of error when uninstalling Store. When I uninstalled the add-ons, nothing was left in the DB in reference to either add-on and the only thing in EE was its listing in modules and ability to install it. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Can you look in th exp_fieldtypes table for "store" and for the subscription one (not sure of exact name in table). Also check the exp_extensions table for class called "Store_ext" and again, the subscription one. Are they there? Do you have any custom add-ons or third-party add-ons that might rely on these add-ons?

Comment: No custom add-ons or third-party add-ons that rely on Subscriptions or Store.

Comment: (Hit Return too fast.) The fieldtype for Subscriptions in exp_fieldtypes is subs_plan_selector. When it's installed, it's there. When I uninstall the module, it's gone but that's when the error shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go to Add Ons -> Fieldtypes in the Admin, it shows fieldtypes that are not installed to give the option of installing. So it will read the file ft.subs_plan_selector.php even if its not installed.

Unfortunately the file ft.subs_plan_selector.php is calling subs/autoload.php right at the top, which will go onto calling the AddOns other methods and functions which will include reading the table, which doesn't exist of course as its uninstalled.

Moving the uninstalled subs folder out of third_party (delete from server) fixed this for me.

Although it should be addressed by DevDemon of course. The expected behaviour is the subs folder can sit in third_party uninstalled and not affect the site.

Comment: Yep. It wasn't limited to just Subscriptions though. Had to have EllisLab help out (I didn't even think about trying to move the folder out of third party - <facepalm>). Meant to post the answer but I forgot. Yours works though. :)